# How to register the right answer from a dropdown list in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

When I run my application, the class shows a list with multiple choices (in this case A or B).

## class in Python:

```
class ListActif(BoxLayout):

    def submit_input6(self):
        var_actif_selection = self.actif_selection_input.text
        resultat_input[5] = var_actif_selection
```

## class in kivy lang (.kv):

```
<ListActif>:
    actif_selection_input: actif_selection
    name: 'ActifDown'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            id: boutn
            text: '-'
            on_release: actifdown.open(self)
            on_parent: actifdown.dismiss()
            ActifDown:
                id: actifdown
                on_select: boutn.text = 'Selected actif: {}'.format(args[1])
                on_select: root.submit_input6()
                Button:
                    id: actif_selection
                    text: 'Value A'
                    pos: self.parent.pos
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_release: actifdown.select('A')
                Button:
                    id: actif_selection
                    text: 'Value B'
                    pos: self.parent.pos
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_release: actifdown.select('B')
```

Whatever the user is selecting, the answer registered by the python class 'ListActif' is always the 'A' option.
How should I define my 'id' to adapt it to the right answer?

Comment: Is `ActifDown` a `DropDown`/`Spinner` or what is it actually? Something runnable would be nice :)

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr - Seems like a Popup and a Spinner

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure (Since your example is not *run-able*) but I noticed that you are defining the same callback twice:

```
     on_select: boutn.text = 'Selected actif: {}'.format(args[1])
     on_select: root.submit_input6()
```

This means that the first one is ignored, maybe this is the **issue**